# Selenium web driver :Click on photo and page rediret

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a home page with employee photo. If i click on the photo , it redirects me to employee profile page. 
How to automate this using page object model , selenium Web driver/testNg.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you are asking. Please provide `html`, screenshot etc to help you out

Comment: home page contains a photo. if i click any where in the photo, it should redirect me to that employee's profile page.

Comment: which site r you using??

Comment: you have to choose the xpath of that photo. then findElement for that xpath,click on it. It will redirect to the selected employee profile page.

Comment: Please provide your html code, and what did you already try?

Comment: <div class="smallbox">
<div class="title">
<h2>My doctor</h2>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="" data-ng-show="signOnFlag">
<div class="ng-hide" data-ng-hide="signOnFlag">
</div>

Comment: what will be xpath of smallbox( I too have another class same as smallbox).so cant write "//div/*[@class='smallbox].

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is something like this a file "home_page.py"

```
class HomePage(object):
   def __init__(self, driver):
       self.driver = driver
       self.url = "http://www.homepage.com/"
       self.employee_photo - = "//a[@class='employee_photo']/img"


   def goto_homepage(self):
       self.driver.get(self.url)

   def get_employee_photo(self):
       return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.employee_photo)

   def click_on_employee_photo(self):
       photo = self.get_employee_photo()
       photo.click()
```

In your test file:

```
from home_page import HomePage
from selenium import webdriver

class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def test_clicking_employee_photo_redirects(self):
    home_page = HomePage(self.driver)
    home_page.goto_homepage()
    employee_photo_url = home_page.get_employee_photo().get_attribute('href')
    home_page.click_on_employee_photo()
    redirect_page_url = self.driver.current_url
    self.assertEqual(redirect_page_url, employee_photo_url)
```

So that is the basics. If I understand correctly what you are looking for.